# Pagination with mongoTemplate findDistinct

Tags: spring-data, spring-mongo, mongotemplate

I'm using custom query to select a field using `findDistinct` method. I tried passing pageRequest to the query using `with` method, I still got the full results. Is there any way to get the results of findDistinct paginated?

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("socialAction").in(socialActions));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userId").is(userId));
if (excludedSubjectIds != null) {
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("subjectId").nin(excludedSubjectIds));
}
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 15);
query.with(pageRequest);
List<String> subjectId = mongoTemplate.findDistinct(query, "subjectId", SocialUserHistory.class, String.class);
```

I expected 15 subjectIds, but currently I am getting all of the subjectIds.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that `find` methods cannot be paginated by default. Here might be solution for this: https://medium.com/@AADota/spring-mongo-template-pagination-92fa93c50d5c

Comment: I tried using PageableExecutionUtils but the resulting page still contained more than 15 rows.